# Oracle SQL, Search for string in one column that contains string from another column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

Currently have this table, and need to be able to find Sentences that contain the name of a person

```
ID         FIRSTNAME       LASTNAME        EMAIL                         PHRASE
--------  --------------- ------------     ---------------------------   ---------------------------------------------------------------          
1          John            Smith           jsmith@faker.com              I'm the same as other people.
2          Sarah           Lane            saralane23@faker.com          I'm different from other people
3          Allen           Borazt          allenB@faker.com              I guess I need another job.
4          Mike            Himmy           mh@faker.com                  We have a great time. John Smith really enjoys his time out.
5          Jillian         Carters         jcartrs@faker.com             What happened to the car? 
6          Steven          Oarts           SteveO2@faker.com             Just chillin' over in the pool
7          Ronald          Donalds         don@faker.com                 Just in case you were wondering
8          Nancy           Arist           nArist@faker.com              What I really want is Paul Blarts movie.
9          Paul            Blart           paulb@faker.com               I think Nancy Arist hair color is cool.
```

Right now my query looks like this but it returns "No Rows Selected".

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Table T
WHERE T.Phrase Like '%' || T.FirstName || '%';
```

My desired result would look like this.

```
ID         FIRSTNAME       LASTNAME        EMAIL                         PHRASE
--------  --------------- ------------     ---------------------------   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------               
4          Mike            Himmy           mh@faker.com                  We have a great time. John Smith really enjoys his time out.
8          Nancy           Arist           nArist@faker.com              What I really want is Paul Blarts movie.
9          Paul            Blart           paulb@faker.com               I think Nancy Arist hair color is cool.
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  You may look into using full text search.

Comment: So basically finding any phrase that contains the firstname or lastname of a person

Comment: I cannot find the table and sample data for colimn1

Comment: Sorry i was gonna post this with random table names, but thought it might be easier to read if i put data, just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a sub query and use exists to check if that fname or lname is found in phrase column.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM Table1 A
WHERE EXISTS (
          SELECT * 
           FROM Table1 B
           WHERE B.Phrase Like '%' || A.FirstName || '%'
           OR  B.Phrase Like '%' || A.LastName  || '%')
```

Comment: Phrase was defined in the same table, its all in one. Looking online it said I may need to use a subquery, but doing your solution still resulted in "No Rows Selected"

Comment: i didnt scroll to the right so dod not see the column phrase. i updated my answer

Comment: Nice!, Thanks so much this worked, just added a trim over the name parts and got my query

Answer (score 1):

Hmmmm.  The problem is that you are looking only at the values within a single row.  I think you want:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t.Phrase Like '%' || t2.FirstName || '%'
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

> Adding a query to ignore case sensitivity

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM Table T1, Table T2
WHERE upper(T1.Phrase) Like '%' || upper(T2.FirstName) || '%'
OR upper(T1.Phrase) Like '%' || upper(T2.LastName) || '%';
```